# Debian 12 system randomly hangs after suspend or hibernation

Tags: debian, suspend, crash, hibernate, hang

It's a laptop from 2010 that has been running XP, Debian 9, Windows 10 and now this new Debian 12 system, and only in this last one it shows this problem: sometimes it resumes ok from suspend or hibernation, but sometimes it hangs a few seconds after resuming.

It's weird because it's not totally stalled for a while: caps lock LED turns on and off, I can Alt-Tab and the white border of the next window shows but not the contents. I can do CTRL+ALT+F2 and the text console shows, I type the username but I never get the Password: prompt. After that it totally hangs and even the caps lock LED does not change. Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work either. Interestingly, it still answers to ping from other PC in the LAN, but a ssh connection can't be established

Sometimes (very rarely) it has happened without suspending but after sitting there idle for some minutes, it is running ok while it was sitting idle (I can see that because the tray clock shows the correct time) but after some clicks or commands it hangs and the clock stops updating

I tried:

- disconnecting all external devices like USB mouse and USB sticks
- using the suspend/hibernate commands in XFCE menu as well as `pm-suspend`, `systemctl suspend`, and `echo -n mem > /sys/power/state`
- checking different log files in `/var/log`: they don't show anything related to the crash (the timestamps go from the last seconds of running correctly, to the new boot)

The only thing I can think of is that for the first time I'm using an encrypted swap partition (both `/` and `swap` were configured with LUKS with the Debian installer). Could this be the problem?

Comment: If you're using proprietary drivers (eg: nvidial GPU), you might have to check if this happens when not using them. Because if  in the end you'd have to do a bug report about the linux kernel, having a proprietary driver will not help the resolution of this bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine for a couple of days:

The main problem is that I can't check logs as the crash makes it impossible to write to the log file, so in cases like this one should `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a Terminal window and leave that window at the front so you can read it when it crashes. Another option would be sending those logs to another machine in the network.

There I could see some HDD errors:

[image: syslog]

I don't know why the system performs Discard on a HDD, but anyway I remembered that the BIOS setting for the HDD was in IDE mode and not AHCI, changed it and know it works fine.